# iphone scrollview and imageview autoresize

Tags: ios, imageview, scrollview, autoresize

I am using xcode 4.3.2.

I have an `imageView` inside a `scrollView`, with the `contentMode` for both set as aspect fill.

My problem is after I rotate the orientation, the screen focuses on the center of the image.

When I scroll down there is a blank part under the image. 
When I try to scroll up, it bounce me back, so actually I cannot stay at the top of `scrollView`

I set the `contentsize` of the scroll view to the size of the actual image showed on phone(not the original image size),

The origin of both of the frames are 0, 0 so anyone can help resolve this issue when i rotate the phone.